# Escape single quote (') when update Google Sheets through API v4

Tags: android, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was able to update cells in Google Spreadsheets using API v4.
One of the column is to embed image from url.
I'm doing it by adding text like this.

```
"=image(\"http://mydomain/app/uploads/IMG_001.jpg\")"
```

However, in my spreadsheets, Google automatically add a leading single quote which make the formula as text.

```
'=image("http://mydomain/app/uploads/IMG_001.jpg")
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar by sending `stringValue` updates to the API. It's adding that damn single-quote as part of the value. Still trying to find an answer.

Comment: I had the same problem using C# and the solution was to set ValueInputOption to USERENTERED instead of RAW. I guess it's similar in Android/Java

Answer (score 7):

Use  `valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"`, Instead of  `valueInputOption: "RAW"`,